# What's the use case for signed SAML IdP metadata?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

Is having signed metadata useful in any way outside of the initial metadata exchange? What are the risks in skipping the signature the signature check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only to secure the initial exchange. About the risks. Its recommended to secure the transport of thw meta data in some way to ensure trust. This is just one more alternative to ensure trust.  If you trust the channel where the metadata is delivered, there is no need to sign